# Gauging Azure DevOps parallel pipeline needs

Tags: azure-pipelines

We're considering switching the build portion of our Azure DevOps pipelines from self-hosted to Microsoft-hosted. Part of the evaluation is to understand how many parallel pipelines would be needed.

**Do tools exist that help to gauge how many parallel pipelines would be needed given current pipeline usage in the organization?**

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Parallel jobs in organization settings. Please refer to this document about [How many parallel jobs do I need](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted#how-many-parallel-jobs-do-i-need).

**Update**:

Here is the sample if you want to use Rest API to view the in-progress jobs:

1.Self-hosted in private project:

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/_apis/distributedtask/resourceusage?parallelismTag=Private&poolIsHosted=false&includeRunningRequests=true
```

2.Self-hosted in public project:

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/_apis/distributedtask/resourceusage?parallelismTag=Public&poolIsHosted=false&includeRunningRequests=true
```

You can find the following information in the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have observed that page, but this is not a viable approach, since it would require a lot of manual hours to track the info. Are any metrics kept around this data? Examples: # of blocked pipelines per given period, avg/mean/max duration of blockage, type of pipeline initiation (PR, manual, CI, etc.), visual timeline of usage, etc. Can this info be mapped into ADO analytics area, say, via the REST API?

Comment: @GaTechThomas I think view in-progress jobs is the most convenient way. You can buy more parallel jobs at any time if not enough.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the Rest API and scripts to see if parallel jobs are sufficient. For example, run the API at regular intervals and compare the values of usedCount and totalCount. Please check my update in the answer. Hope this can meet your needs.